# If-condition never executes despite correct condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a simple piece of code to validate a username and a password.

```
    public boolean isValid(String u, String p) {
    if (u=="admin" && p=="password1") {
        return true;
    } else if (u=="user" && p=="password2") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I've tried debugging it, and when it runs, u has the value "admin" and p has the value "password1", but it just skips the first condition. I must have done something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Classical mistake... You don't test string equality using `==`; use `.equals()` instead: `if ("user".equals(u))` etc

Comment: you should use the .equals method for comparison of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` should not be used for String comparison. Use `equals()` instead.