# Condition never returning true

Tags: android, if-statement, timertask

I have an if statement which checks if three slots are finished. If it is, the timer should stop, but the code is not running for some reason. I have seen a post similar to this [If-condition never executes despite correct condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607272/if-condition-never-executes-despite-correct-condition), however their solution solved nothing.

Here is my code:

**Stop function**

```
 public void stop(ImageSwitcher slot){
    slotOneFinished = (slot.equals(slotOne));
    slotTwoFinished = (slot.equals(slotTwo));
    slotThreeFinished = (slot.equals(slotThree));
    if (slotOneFinished&&slotTwoFinished&&slotThreeFinished){
        //not running
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkWin(getFruits());
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

**Timer**

```
private Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!slotOneFinished){
                    animate(randomSwitchCount(), slotOne);
                }
                if (!slotTwoFinished) {
                    animate(randomSwitchCount(), slotTwo);
                }
                if (!slotThreeFinished) {
                    animate(randomSwitchCount(), slotThree);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**Animate function**

```
public void animate(final int maxCount, final ImageSwitcher slot) {
    i++;
    if (i<maxCount){
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.new_slot_item_in);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.old_item_out);
        slot.setInAnimation(in);
        slot.setOutAnimation(out);
        int fruit = randomFruit();
        slot.setTag(fruit);
        slot.setImageResource(fruit);
    }else {
        stop(slot);
    }
}
```

Using == did nothing as well.

Thanks for your help,

PiNet

Comment: I do not think the brackets are necessary when setting slotNumFinished. But that does not solve the issue.

Comment: which lines did't executed?

Comment: I think you have now noticed.But I already commented the block of code which is not running

Comment: How can `slot.equals()` possibly return `true` for three different `ImageSwitchers`?

Comment: that's it! For some reason I though the variable wouldn't change when calling the function again. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition can never be true, assuming that `equals()` is implemented in the canonical way, and `slotOne`, `slotTwo`, and `slotThree` are 3 distinct objects:

```
if (slotOneFinished&&slotTwoFinished&&slotThreeFinished)
```

Looks like you had a mistaken assumption about the scope of the variables. You can probably fix this by using a condition like this, instead:

```
if( slot == slotOne )
    slotOneFinished = true;
```

...and so forth.

The Android Studio debugger is your friend.

Comment: I did the same code when I read your comment. It works fine, thank you.